Convex order between Gamma distributions and Exponential distributions
Let $ (b_1, \dots, b_n) $ be a tuple of positive integers. Define independent random variables $ Y_i \sim \text{Gamma}(b_i, b_i) $ (shape and rate parameter both equal to $ b_i $) for $( i = 1, \dots, n ).$ Also, let $ X_i \sim \text{Exp}(1) $ be $ n $ i.i.d. random variables from an Exponential distribution with rate $1.$
I am interested in proving the inequality:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\max(Y_1, \dots, Y_n)\right) \leq \mathbb{E}\left(\max(X_1, \dots, X_n)\right)
$$
where the right-hand side is known to be $ 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} $.
It seems that convex order could be a useful approach here since the maximum function is convex. For example, if we could prove that $Y_i \leq_{cx} X_i$, we have $ \mathbb{E}(Y_i) = \mathbb{E}(X_i) $ and $ \text{Var}(Y_i) \leq \text{Var}(X_i) $, which is true because  $$ \mathbb{E}(Y_i) = 1 = \mathbb{E}(X_i),$$ $$\text{Var}(Y_i) = 1/b_i \leq 1 = \text{Var}(X_i).$$
I am curious whether there are established results or literature that directly address this inequality.
Additionally, does convex order theory provide a formal framework for this comparison? Specifically, if $ X_i \leq_{cx} Y_i $ for independent random variables, does it follow that $ (X_1, \dots, X_n) \leq_{cx} (Y_1, \dots, Y_n) $.
Any references or foundational papers would be highly appreciated. Thank you for any insights or guidance!

This seems to be true if each $b_i \ge 1$ but not necessarily integers.  It does not seem to be true if each $b_i \lt 1$, in which case your variance inequality reverses.

@Henry : You are right, and this follows by a very slight modification of my answer.

On the other hand, perhaps you can generalise the positive integer $b_i$ statement to saying that if the i.i.d. $X$s have finite expectations (so much more general than exponential distributions) and $Y_i=\frac{1}{b_i}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{b_i} X_{ij}$, then $\mathbb E\left[\max(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)\right]$ is maximised when each $b_i=1$. It seems intuitively plausible as the averaging in $Y_i$ would narrow its distribution.

$\newcommand\R{\Bbb R}$We will show that your conjecture is true.
(You have interchanged the roles of $X_i$ and $Y_i$. We will continue to assume that $X_i\sim\text{Gamma}(b_i,b_i)$ with $b_i\ge1$ and $Y_i \sim \text{Gamma}(1,1)=\text{Exp}(1)$, with the corrected direction of the conjectured inequality. In fact, we will assume, more generally, that $X_i\sim\text{Gamma}(b_i,b_i)$ and $Y_i \sim \text{Gamma}(a_i,a_i)$ with $0<a_i\le b_i$ for all $i$, without assuming that any of the $b_i$'s or any of the $a_i$'s are integers.)

Lemma 1:
$$Eh(X_1)\le Eh(Y_1)$$
for any convex function $h\colon\R\to\R$.

The proof of this lemma will be given at the end of this answer.
It follows from Lemma 1 that
$$EF(X_1,\dots,X_n)\le EF(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$$
for any real-valued function $F$ of $n$ real arguments that is convex in each of its arguments. In particular,
$$E\max(X_1,\dots,X_n)\le E\max(Y_1,\dots,Y_n).$$
Indeed, letting
$$e_i:=EF(X_1,\dots,X_i,Y_{i+1},\dots,Y_n)$$
for $i=0,\dots,n$, we have
$$\begin{aligned}&e_i \\
&=\int_{\R^{n-1}}EF(x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},X_i,y_{i+1},\dots,y_n)
\prod_{j=1}^{i-1}P(X_j\in dx_j)\,\prod_{j=i+1}^n P(Y_j\in dy_j) \\ 
&\le \int_{\R^{n-1}}EF(x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},Y_i,y_{i+1},\dots,y_n)
\prod_{j=1}^{i-1}P(X_j\in dx_j)\,\prod_{j=i+1}^n P(Y_j\in dy_j) \\ 
&=e_{i-1}
\end{aligned}$$
for $i=1,\dots,n$.
So,
$$EF(X_1,\dots,X_n)=e_n\le e_0=EF(Y_1,\dots,Y_n).\quad\Box$$

Proof of Lemma 1:
Since $Eh(X_1)=Eh(Y_1)$ for affine functions $h$, and because $X_1\ge0$ and $Y_1\ge0$, it is enough to show that $Eh_t(X_1)\le Eh_t(Y_1)$ for all real $t\ge0$, where $h_t(x):=\max(0,x-t)$. That is, we have to show that
$$d(t):=d(a,b,t):=e(b,t)-e(a,t)\le0 \tag{10}\label{10}$$
for $t\ge0$, where $0<a<b$ and
$$e(b,t):=Eh_t(X_1)=\frac{\Gamma (b+1,b t)-b t\, \Gamma (b,b t)}{b \Gamma (b)}. $$
Note that
$$d''(t)\frac{\Gamma(b)}{b^b}t^{1-a}e^{a t}
=e^{t (a-b)} t^{b-a}-\frac{a^a b^{-b} \Gamma (b)}{\Gamma (a)},$$
which is either

$<0$ for all $t>0$ or
$>0$ for $t\in(A,B)$ and $<0$ for $t\in(0,A)\cup(B,\infty)$, for some real $A$ and $B$ such $0<A<B$.

So, $d$ is either

concave on $(0,\infty)$ or
convex on $(A,B)$ and concave on $(0,A)$ and on $(B,\infty)$.

Also, $d(0)=0=d'(0)$ and $d(\infty-)=0$ (by the way, this actually shows that the first alternative under each of the two instances of "either" cannot possibly hold). So, we have \eqref{10}. $\quad\Box$

Dear Iosif, Thanks for your answer! There is an issue that my parameters are shape and rate. So the quotient f_X(x)/f_Y(x) should be of the form c x^{b-1} e^{(1-b)x}, which is not an increasing function.

@RandyJi : Then the conjecture will not hold, as is now shown.

Hi Iosif, Thanks for you answer. My conjecture is that the expectation of the max of Gamma distribution is smaller than that of max of exponential distribution, which does not violate your numerical example.

@RandyJi : This is not what you wrote. Anyhow, the corrected conjecture is now proved.

Thanks for you detailed answer! Sorry that I just realized the notations in my question were not typed as what I wanted.

I think a slight modification of this answer will extend it to the case when $X_i\sim\text{Gamma}(b_i,b_i)$ and $Y_i\sim\text{Gamma}(a_i,a_i)$ with $b_i\ge a_i>0$ for all $i$.

Now this modification is carried out.

Thanks, Iosif! The proof and this generalization is really nice!
